# Passing collection of string as arguments to JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

There is this function.

```js
var cache = [];
$.preLoadImages = function() {
  var args_len = arguments.length;
  for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
    cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
    cache.push(cacheImage); console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```js
$.preLoadImages("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png");
```

I need to store several image urls in a variable and then pass it to the function.
"arguments" type is Object, so I have dealt with an object or array but It doesn´t works.
Do you have any idea on how to pass the urls collection to that function?

Answer (score 6):

Store the URLs in an array, and then do this:

```
var imageURLs = [ "url1", "url2", "url3", ... ];

$.preLoadImages.apply($, imageURLs);
```

The `.apply()` function takes an array and uses it as the list of arguments for a function invocation.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the places you'd use `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply